# SQLite In Clause not working in trigger

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, dapper

> i have two tables Table1 and Table2. Table1 have columns ID,stringIDs and Table2 Columns ID,data
>
> [image: There are two tables in picture]
>
> i have created a trigger to delete rows based on table1.
>       it doesn't works  if comma Seperated stringIDs 
>       are more than one. it works if stringIDs is only single value

```
create trigger tgTriggerName after delete
on Table1
begin
delete from Table2 where ID in (old.stringIDs);
end
```

Comment: The code works fine.  You just don't understand the difference between a list of string values and a string containing a list of values.  Your data structure is bad.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table, not a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your concern , i am using sqlite i think, that column doen't makes any difference on delete trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'stringIDs' from table1 save them in another table with foreign key reference than apply trigger on new table to delete records from table 2

Answer (score 2):

Gordon is right, this table structure is *really* probably not what you want. But if for some reason you must do it this way, this query might accomplish what you want:

```
delete from Table2 
where ID = old.stringIDs                   -- ID matches exactly
  or old.stringIDs like ID + ',%'          -- Or ID is at beginning of list
  or old.stringIDs like '%,' + ID          -- Or ID is at end of list
  or old.stringIDs like '%,' + ID + ',%'   -- Or ID is in middle of list
```

But that's a mess. Don't do it. Instead remove the stringIDs column from Table1, and add a column to Table2 called `Table1ID` to indicate which Table1 ID this Table2 record belongs to. So Table2 would look like this

```
ID     Table1ID     Data
1      1            some data
2      1            some data
3      2            some data
4      2            some data
5      2            some data
...
```

Then your trigger query can simply be:

```
delete from Table2
where Table1ID = old.ID
```

Even more clean would be to skip the trigger completely and do a Foreign Key Contstraint with cascading delete. But I have a feeling that's a lesson for another day.